# How to compare KeyEventArgs to a character?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a `TextEdit.PreviewKeyDown` method where I want to check if an input character is equal to a special character of my choosing.

For an instance I want to check if the user's input character is '#'. I'd use:

```
if(e.Key == Key.D3 && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift)
```

The problem is I don't know what the special character will be at the time and I can't possibly program all the cases, so I wanted something like:

```
string strSpecChar = GetSpecialCharacter();

if(strSpecChar = e.Key) {do_sth();}
```

Which doesn't work at all, because if I press, for example '3', the `e.Key` value will be equal to 'D3', so if my strSpecChar value is '3' I can't get to the do_sth()

I have browsed through the `System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs` docs and I've found nothing and I've also read some discouraging posts on other forums.

Is there any way I would be able to compare the `PreviewKeyDown` e and string strSpecChar?

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string strNewLigneSign = String.Empty;
    if (InsertTextDialogHelper != null)
        strNewLigneSign = InsertTextDialogHelper.GetNewLineSign();

    if (e.Key.Equals(strNewLigneSign))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strNewLigneSign))
        {
            int strCaretPosition = TextBox.CaretIndex;
            e.Handled = true;

            string strNewText = "\r\n";
            CurrentDialogData.TextValue = CurrentDialogData.TextValue.Insert(strCaretPosition, strNewText);
            TextBox.CaretIndex = strCaretPosition + strNewText.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

As per @mm8's suggestion I tried to implement it in the `TextEdit.PreviewTextInput` property as follows:

XAML

```
<dxe:TextEdit Name="TextBox"
    PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" \">
</dxe:TextEdit>
```

C#

```
  private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
  {
     string strNewLigneSign = String.Empty;
     if(InsertTextDialogHelper != null)
        strNewLigneSign = InsertTextDialogHelper.GetNewLineSign();

     if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strNewLigneSign))
     {
        if(e.Text.Contains(strNewLigneSign))
        {
           int strCaretPosition = TextBox.CaretIndex;
           e.Handled = true;

           string strNewText = Unhashify(e.Text);
           CurrentDialogData.TextValue =  CurrentDialogData.TextValue.Insert(strCaretPosition, strNewText);
           TextBox.CaretIndex = strCaretPosition + strNewText.Length;
        }
     }
  }
```

However when I run the app and set the breakpoints anywhere inside that method it seems never to go inside it. 
The exact same solution worked for me back when I used it in wpf's TextBox, but as soon as I switched to devexpress,  the `TextBox_PreviewTextInput` method is never called.

Comment: In general, a key on the keyboard (retrieved by `KeyEventArgs`) does not correspond to a particular character - this depends on the keyboard layout. E.g. Shift+3 can yield different characters for German and for English layouts.

Answer (score 3):

A key is a key and not a character. It's *eventually* mapped to a character depending on the input device.

You may want to consider handling `PreviewTextInput` and check the value of `Text[0]` of the `TextCompositionEventArgs` instead of handling `PreviewKeyDown`.

Comment: I tried to implement the TextEdit.PreviewTextInput property but it seems like it doesn't work at all. I put a breakpoint inside it but it never breaks.

Comment: Did you try to hook up an event handler for `this.PreviewTextInput` in the constructor of a window? It works for me.

Comment: No, I haven't. Can I find an example somewhere? I browsed devexpress forum but I only found one which didn't work for me.